# terminated java application javaw.exe eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing, automation

I created a simple script of opening a webpage using selenium tool. and my program is terminated without even opening the browser. I have attached all the relevant jar files and set the JAVA path too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Change "Firefoxdriver driver" to "Webdriver driver" in line no 9
2. You can remove geckodriver.exe from the external jars.
3. Copy the geckodriver.exe to a folder in C: drive.
4. Ensure you are providing the correct path of gecko driver.
5. The driver name should be "gecko driver.exe"

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help you out.